# Redirecting assembly method at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to redirect a method from a `System` assembly. I've tried to redirect methods from two assemblies so far: `System.Text.Encoding` and `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

In both instances I end up with the following exception:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 

'Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

If I apply the redirection code to my own assemblies it works as intended.

The following is the complete test program I've been using which targets the `GetEncodings` method of the `System.Text.Encoding` assembly:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;

namespace RuntimeMethodReplace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings());

            Injection.Install();

            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings());

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    internal static class Injection
    {
        public static EncodingInfo[] GetEncodings()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static void Install()
        {
            var methodToReplace = typeof(System.Text.Encoding).GetMethod("GetEncodings");
            var methodToInject = typeof(Injection).GetMethod("GetEncodings");

            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);

            unsafe
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    var inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
                    var tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
#if DEBUG
                    var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;

                    var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (int)injInst + 5 + *injSrc - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                    *tar = *inj;
#endif
                }
                else
                {
                    var inj = (long*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                    var tar = (long*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
#if DEBUG
                    var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;

                    var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (int)injInst + 5 + *injSrc - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                    *tar = *inj;
#endif
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on line 65, which is the following bit of code in the else statement of the above:

```cs
*tarSrc = (int)injInst + 5 + *injSrc - ((int)tarInst + 5);
```

I'm currently speculating whether I get this exception because the `System.Text.Encoding` assembly runs in a separate application domain (?). I would appreciate any tips or answers that can point me to the solution.

Comment: Is this just for fun, or are you trying to solve an actual problem? Anyway, it's possible that the method you are trying to redirect hasn't been jit'ted yet, so the code pointer is invalid. Try calling it first.

Comment: I have old projects that depend heavily on some utility functions from external assemblies that are not viable going forward. Instead of throwing everything out or doing major refactoring work I thought I would investigate the possibility of replacing these dependencies with my own implementations. I do call the method initially before redirecting in the first line of my Main method.